# Problem with Selection tool in Adobe Illstrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, selections

My selection tool icon in adobe illustrator has changed to a triangle, Does anyone know what that means and how I can turn it back to the arrow icon?

[image]

Comment: Has the functionality changed?  It looks to me like somehow the selection tool and the direct selection tool have changed places in your toolbar. In situations like this I always try restarting and resetting my preferences (Alt+Control+Shift (Windows) or Option+Command+Shift (Mac OS)) and most of the time that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately resting the preferences didn't help

Comment: Sorry...that's all I got on this one! :-(

Comment: Looks like these are the new selection icons. I just recently updated to CC 2017 and it seems this is the way it is now.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I just reinstalled the software and those icons are still there :)

Answer (score 1):

These are the new icons for the selection tools in Illustrator CC (2017).

From the "Illustrator New features" section on the Adobe Illustrator page:

> **Modern user experience**
>   A flat UI and new icons for tools and panels offer a cleaner look and help you focus on your artwork.

[Illustrator CC New Features](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/illustrator/features.html)

I don't think there is a built in way to change them back.